# Appendix issues while adding in thesis in lyx document

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, appendices, thesis

I am trying to add appendix at the end of  my thesis after references in LyX,
Document-> Start appendix here
But I am not getting where I am doing wrong as it doesn't come in `TOC`, please guide me what should I do??

```
\appendix
\noindent \begin{center}
\textbf{Questionnaire (Case Study 1)}
\par\end{center}
```

Comment: This is the same question like the other one you posted about an hour ago. It depends on the documentclass and on the way `\chapter` or `\chapter*` are used. You provided no further information, unfortunately

Comment: I am using article (standard) class

Comment: None of the commands above makes entries to the ToC.